# Using ethereum address as primary key in SQL database

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, solidity

Users in my app won't authenticate with standard authentication.

Rather, when they create an ethereum wallet like MetaMask, their public ethereum address (`char(42)`) will be their identity.

This poses some dilemma for me as for what will be the primary key to identify users in SQL, since there really isn't something like `createUser`.

42 characters seems like a long string to query, as tradeoff against a regular primary key. So how do you solve this dilemma?

Comment: I’m sorry, why do you think you can’t use a “regular primary key”. If you have a table of Users, the “username” is generally not the PK. Why do you think that’s different here?

Comment: @vol7ron The situation is a bit different here, because there isn't something like user registration. The user account is generated by the ethereum wallet.

Comment: I’m struggling to detect the meaningful difference. Instead of the user typing in a username, isn’t the wallet is generating it? In both cases the database is just storing a [potentially unique] value

Comment: @vol7ron Yes. What I meant with the question was that there isn't for example an auto-generated integer or UUID on creation of the user which is much more common and I suppose more performant. The user is sort of 'always there' if you see what I mean. So I would need to check if a user exists every time the user wants to create a post (since there is no userId from the database on authentication, as there is no authentication), which seems a bit silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How much Users are we walking about? If we don't talk about more than 1M or more you should be totally fine with just having the 42 chars as the index and primary key and then just create an index on it. Also you can just use varchar without the length parameter as it doesn't really matter anyway

Answer (score 1):

You might not want to have a 42 character key lurking in the database, occupying space in indexes that refer to users and other tables where something like 42 - 4 bytes are unnecessary.

I would recommend a synthetic key:

```
create table users (
    user_id int generated always as identity primary key,
    ethereum_key char(42) unique not null,
    . . .
);
```

In older versions of Postgres, you would use:

```
    user_id serial primary key,
```

You can use the `int` `user_id` throughout the database.  Lookup `ethereum_key` where you need to.

Comment: When will you create this user? I can imagine it's not very sensible to check user existence to creation on every page visit, or every time we want to make a query on userId.

Comment: "*occupying space in indexes*" - the unique constraint creates an index as well which is just as big as the primary key index would be. I don't see how this would improve anything - in fact it just adds an index that would probably never be used as all queries will probably retrieve the rows based on the ethereum key (and there is absolutely no advantages of using `char(42)` over `varchar(42)`)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . . . I mean in indexes that *refer* to users, not in the indexes for this table.  I am aware of the `char()`/`varchar()` equivalence, but the OP uses `char()` in the question.

Comment: @Trace . . . You can use `insert . . . on conflict` to insert a new user when you need.  Or just `select` to see if a particular key already exists.

Comment: I see. But application wise this creates a lot of needless clutter as you would need to perform the check on every call that requires the userId.